# Formatting Issues With Textarea Height and Margins

Tags: html, css, height, textarea, margin

I've been doing a coding project for school, and on one of the pages, my textarea boxes have been giving me some trouble. They need to have 5% left and right margins, but I can tell that the left and right margins are slightly different, so I just wanted to try and figure out what that was about. Also I need to be able to set the height of the textarea boxes to a percentage so that it's relative to the screen size, but the only way I was able to alter the height of them was by setting it to a pixel measurement.

The css for the two textarea boxes looks like this:

```
#input {
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

#output {
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

...and you can access the final result of that page [here](https://jsfiddle.net/casuallysentient/9s4ux57t/2/).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code in itself.  Just to see if this works...try adding the following to your css

```
html { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

The other thing you could try is adding a float or display property to your textareas.  Something like `float: left;` or `display: block;`

See if that does what you are wanting.